# MongoDB Aggregation pipeline problems

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

I'm new to mongoDB and am having difficulty getting my head around aggregation pipelines.

I have created a database that holds information regarding my stock trading. In a cut down version one document from my portfolio collection looks a bit like this

```
   {
   "date" : 2015-12-31T15:50:00.000Z,
   "time" : 1550,
   "aum"  : 1000000,
   "basket" :[
   {
     "_id" : "Microsoft",
     "shares" : 10,
     "price"  : 56.53,
     "fx"     : 1.0
   },
   .
   .
   .
   {
     "_id" : "GOOG.N",
     "shares" : 20,
     "price"  : 759.69,
     "fx"     : 1.0
   }
```

]

So, for each day, I keep track of my assets under management (aum) and a list of all the positions I hold with the current price. What I need to do is to calculate the daily net and gross exposure for the portfolio as a percentage of aum. Net exposure is simply:

`sum(shares*price*fx)/aum`

over all the stocks. Gross exposure is:

`abs(shares*price*fx)/aum`

(a negative position means a short position). I need to do this as a single query using the aggregation framework. I have tried numbers of queries but none seem to work so clearly I'm just wandering around in the dark. Can anyone give some guidance?

My query looks like this

```
db.strategy.aggregate(

  // Pipeline
  [
    // Stage 1
    {
      $project: {
        "_id": 0,
        "date":1,
        "time":1,
        "aum":1,
        "strategyName":1,
        "gExposure": {$divide: ["$grossExposure","$aum"]}
      }
    },

    // Stage 2
    {
      $group: {
        _id :{ date:"$date",time:"$time",strategyName:"$strategyName"},
        grossExposure: { $sum: { $abs: {$multiply: [ "$basket.sysCurShares","$basket.price","$basket.fx" ] } }}
      }
    },

    // Stage 3
    {
      $sort: {
      "_id.date": 1,  "_id.time": 1,  "_id.strategyName": 1 
      }
    }

  ]
);
```

The query runs but the calculated value is zero. My projection isn't working as I'd expect either as I would like all the data flattened to a two dimensional table.

Comment: The SO community is inclined to help more if you could demonstrate what you have tried, regardless of whether it's not working or not. Can you show the queries you've tried?

Comment: I agree. I've added my current attempt

Comment: Just to confirm, is the `$grossExposure` field in your first `$project` pipeline step a pre-calculated field, because it's not in the original document schema, or that's the concept which you are struggling with?

Comment: What I was trying to do was to get the aggregated field grossExposure to appear in the projection. I don't think it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the basket field is an array, you need to flatten it using **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** before running the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** aggregate operation. Also, create a new field in the ***[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)*** that holds the exposure before the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline. Continuing from your previous attempt, you could try the following pipeline:

```
db.strategy.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$basket" },
    {
        "$project": {
            "date": 1,
            "time": 1,          
            "strategyName": 1,
            "exposure": { 
                "$multiply": ["$basket.sysCurShares", "$basket.price", "$basket.fx"] 
            }
        }
    },    
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": { 
                "date": "$date",
                "time": "$time",
                "strategyName": "$strategyName"
            },
            "totalExposure": { "$sum": "$exposure" },
            "aum": { "$first": "$aum" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "date": "$_id.date",
            "time": "$_id.time",         
            "strategyName": "$_id.strategyName",
            "netExposure": { "$divide": ["$totalExposure", "$aum"] },
            "grossExposure": {
                "$abs": { "$divide": ["$totalExposure", "$aum"] } 
            }
        }
    }, 
    { "$sort": { "date": 1,  "time": 1,  "strategyName": 1 } }
]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I'll give it a go and report back. Clearly I need to read up about the unwind stage.

Comment: I think that has worked however it looks like the calculations for gross and net exposure are being downcast to integers and so I can't see the result as the exposure as % of aum is always < 1.0. Is there a way of forcing a type on the outcome?

Comment: Somehow I'm failing to grasp the formulas, is it `(sum(shares*price*fx))/aum` or `sum((shares*price*fx)/aum)`? For more details of the arithmetic operators, refer to the [**docs**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-arithmetic/)

Comment: The former (sum(shares*price*fx))/aum

Comment: The query runs and the data is flattened (which is perfect) but the calculated numbers are null. I'll have to sit and look at what you are doing as you are very close.

Comment: I think I know why, the expression`"$multiply": ["$basket.shares", "$basket.price", "$basket.fx"]` might be the culprit since it's different from the one you have. To debug a pipeline that's giving you unxepected results, run the aggregation query at each pipeline stage, test whether the results tally for each step. So for example, in the aggregation above, I first run `db.strategy.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$basket" }]`, check the result to see if the `basket` array is deconstructed properly, add the next pipeline stage, run that and repeat the steps till you get to the final step.

Comment: I will do. Thanks for your help. I thought mongodb would be easy enough if understood SQL but it's clearly more complicated than I expected :(

Comment: No worries, you will soon get the hang of it :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123365/discussion-between-richard-b-and-chridam).

Answer (score 0):

you can do the same with mongodb 3.4 in single stage

```
db.strategy.aggregate([
{
  $project:{
        "date": 1,
        "time": 1,          
        "strategyName": 1,   
        "netExposure":{ "$divide": [{"$reduce":{input:"$basket",initialValue:0,in:{$add:[{$multiply: ["$$this.fx","$$this.shares","$$this.price"]},"$$value"]}}}, "$aum"] },
        "grossExposure":{"$abs":{ "$divide": [{"$reduce":{input:"$basket",initialValue:0,in:{$add:[{$multiply: ["$$this.fx","$$this.shares","$$this.price"]},"$$value"]}}}, "$aum"] }}
}, 
{ "$sort": { "date": 1,  "time": 1,  "strategyName": 1 } }
]);
```